# Determine which host(Physical machine) hosting virtual machine(Vmware) based mac address

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, vmware, mac-address

I've a mac address which belongs to VMware virtual machine in my network(about 4k devices).
The virtual machine is used by VMware workstation on some host in my network.
All i got is a mac address of the virtual machine.
Is there any way to find it(by DOS/bash or similiar) without installing PowerCLI on each device or using arp table details(not allways the virtual machines appears there)?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt that this is possible since identifying host information from a guest could be a security concern. However, what you could do if using ”Workstation PRO” is to call the rest api from within the guest - if that sort of traffic is allowed.

Comment: I have a full control of all the network devices, which uses an adminitration user. is there anyway to use this permission to query the hosts to find if the virtual machine MAC address is used on them?